# spring-data-jpa :- Not an managed type Error

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

Spring Data JPA is not recognising my entity when running tests. Please find code below. We do not use Spring boot.

**JPA Config File(JPAConfigration_Test.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <!--Configing Core JPA Repositories-->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.test.repository"  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory_core" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    <!--    Configring Core Data Resource-->
    <bean id="DS_TEST" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ladvice_service" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />        
    </bean>
    <!--Configring Core System Entity Manager-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory_core" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="LA_Persistence" />        
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DS_TEST" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.test.model" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <!-- always puts logging out to the console...we want it in the log file -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">500</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--Confirgring Core Transaction Manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory_core" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Repository**

```
public interface DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<Demo, Integer> {}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="TESTUSER1")
public class Demo {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

**Persistence**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LA_Persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/JPAConfigration_Test.xml"})
public class LegalRequestRepositoryTest{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void  initiateJNDI() throws IllegalStateException, NamingException{
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
        BasicDataSource basicDataSourceLAdvice = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSourceLAdvice.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        basicDataSourceLAdvice.setUsername("TESTUSER1");
        basicDataSourceLAdvice.setPassword("TESTUSER1");
        basicDataSourceLAdvice.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
        builder.bind( "java:comp/env/jdbc/ladvice_service" , basicDataSourceLAdvice );
        builder.activate();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDEMO(){

    }
}
```

**Fails to Load Application Context. Error I get is**

```
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class org.test.model.Demo
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:173) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spri
```

I am able to connect to the DB and the table does exist. Why does this happen ?

**UPDATE 1**

If the entity is added as  `<class>` in `Persistence.xml` this seems to work. The problem seems to be with `packagesToScan` in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning for entities is only used if *no* persistence unit is defined on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`. You define a persistence unit which doesn't contain any persistent classes so that Hibernate ends up knowing about no classes whatsoever.

You're entire `persistence.xml` seems to be redundant as you just duplicate configuration that's already available on the `LCEMFB`. I suggest to remove it and let Spring scan for entities.

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me now. But we have a working web application which is actually running with the exact same configuration I have asked in the question. The error is happening only in the case of tests. Do you have any idea why this works in a webapp but not in tests.

Comment: I have double checked this again and can confirm that there is a working application with the exact same configuration as in the question above. This does seem strange, but out of curiosity would like to know how they manage to behave in different ways for test and web application.